# Instagram Access Token API: Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am sure that redirect uri is set from Facebook Developer -> Instagram Basic Display -> Basic Display ->

[image: Valid OAuth Redirect URIs].

I have no idea where to check, could you please help me with it? thanks in advance.

**endpoint:**

https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token

**API response:**

```
{
    "error_type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 400,
    "error_message": "Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request"
}
```